# Preciso colocar um Push Button para mudar a direção do motor - Arduino

Tags: arduino

Esse codigo abaixo faz o motor ir pra frente e depois de 3 segundos ir pra tras repetitivamente, porem gostaria que ele fosse pra frente ao clicar no push button e depois ir pra tras ao clicar no push button, estou quebrando muito a cabeça com isso e vejo que é simples porem nao to conseguindo sair dessa parte

estou usando Ponte H circuito L293D

```
# define velmotor 3
# define m1a 4
# define m1b 5
# define tmp 3000

int vel=0;


void setup() {
  pinMode(velmotor, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m1a, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(m1b, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(m1a,LOW);
  digitalWrite(m1b,LOW);
  analogWrite(velmotor,vel);
}

void loop() {
  
  vel=255;
  analogWrite(velmotor,vel);
  digitalWrite(m1a,LOW);
  digitalWrite(m1b,HIGH);
  delay(tmp);
  
  digitalWrite(m1a,LOW);
  digitalWrite(m1b,LOW);
  delay(500);
  
  digitalWrite(m1a,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m1b,LOW);
  delay(tmp);
  digitalWrite(m1a,LOW);
  digitalWrite(m1b,LOW);
  delay(500);

    
      }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

vamos por partes. Vejo que tem alguns problemas com o código, mas vamos devagar. O primeiro passo é aprender como se funciona o push button, para depois a gente misturar com o acionamento do motor. Acredite que isso tudo junto é um pouco complicado para quem não tem prática. Vou deixar um código e um endereço para que depois de atingir este passo possa avançar mais um.

https://blogmasterwalkershop.com.br/arduino/arduino-utilizando-o-push-button/

```
const int pinoBotao = 7; //PINO DIGITAL UTILIZADO PELO PUSH BUTTON
const int pinoLed = 2; //PINO DIGITAL UTILIZADO PELO LED
 
void setup() {
pinMode(pinoBotao, INPUT_PULLUP); //DEFINE O PINO COMO ENTRADA / "_PULLUP" É PARA ATIVAR O RESISTOR INTERNO
  //DO ARDUINO PARA GARANTIR QUE NÃO EXISTA FLUTUAÇÃO ENTRE 0 (LOW) E 1 (HIGH)
pinMode(pinoLed, OUTPUT); //DEFINE O PINO COMO SAÍDA
digitalWrite(pinoLed, LOW); //LED INICIA DESLIGADO
}
void loop(){
  if(digitalRead(pinoBotao) == LOW){ //SE A LEITURA DO PINO FOR IGUAL A LOW, FAZ
      digitalWrite(pinoLed, HIGH); //ACENDE O LED
  }else{ //SENÃO, FAZ
    digitalWrite(pinoLed, LOW); //APAGA O LED
  }
}
```

Vou marcar esta pergunta para acompanhar seu desenvolvimento. Abraços